# Using group by function - count from two different tables , joining over non key field. - SQL /PSQuery

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I have two tables as below , verify and submit. Verify holds all the transactions that were verified and submit hold all the transactions that were submitted. Transactions can be submitted only after verification and all the transactions verified may not be submitted as well.

Now my requirement is to find the count of verified transactions and submitted transactions on a particular date.

### verify Table

```
date    - band                    
4-Jul-18    lpb                 
4-Jul-18    pb                  
4-Jul-18    lpb         
4-Jul-18    pb          
5-Jul-18    lpb         
5-Jul-18    pb          
5-Jul-18    lpb         
5-Jul-18    pb          
5-Jul-18    lpb         
6-Jul-18    lpb
```

### submit table

```
date -  band
4-Jul-18    lpb
5-Jul-18    pb
```

And result should be something like

```
date        - Band - verified cnt - submitted cnt
---------------------------------------------------    
4-Jul-18       lpb          2         1         
4-Jul-18       pb           2         0         
5-Jul-18       lpb          3         0        
5-Jul-18       pb           2         1        
6-Jul-18       lpb          1         0
```

I wrote this query using a subquery to get the count from submit table, and getting count from verify table using group by. But can't use it as its not supported in PSQuery.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to aggregate each of the tables and then bring the results together.  Here is one method:

```
select date, band, sum(num_verified) as num_verified,
       sum(num_submitted) as num_submitted
from (select date, band, count(*) as num_verified, 0 as num_submitted
      from verified
      group by date, band
      union all
      select date, band, 0 as num_verified, count(*) as num_submitted
      from submitted
      group by date, band
     ) vs
group by date, band;
```